# Android application targeting Android SDK Version 26 - Cannot access the application data directory via ADB

Tags: android, adb

I have recently changed my android application to target Android SDK version 26 (previously version 19). When I installed the app on an Oreo device, I tried using ADB to inspect the application's data directory (/data/data/app-package-name) via the ADB shell command. But the command line returned :

> cd: /data/data/app-package-name: Permission denied

I was previously able to access that directory when my app was targeting Android SDK version 19.

Now, I have read a lot of other stack overflow posts on this, the answers to them are usually either you need a rooted device or use some sort of 3rd party libraries.

I noticed that from API 23, Google have introduced a new permission model (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes), so I wonder whether this might have caused the issue I am having.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you had the target on 19 were you also testing on a 19 device? This shouldn't have anything to do with app permissions, but rather the permissions the `shell` user has.

Comment: I tested the application (API 19 & 26) on the same Oreo device (API 26).

Comment: That's weird. But in any case, you shouldn't have been able to do it in the first place, even from ADB. Unfortunately, you were using a bug for your workflow.

Comment: Are you using emulator?

Comment: On rooted devices you can access to that folder otherwise you can't. I think starting from lollipop, genymotion emulators don't have root access by default.

Comment: I am using real device (Google Pixel) with Android Oreo on it.

Answer (score 0):

You must have root access (rooted device) to access that folder. It's not related with runtime permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The internal storage of an application is private to the application and cannot be accessed from other apps unless it is a system app or you have root permissions.

In order to access the internal storage of an application via adb, either the device should be rooted or the **application should be debuggable.** Make sure you are not trying to access the internal storage of an app which is not debuggable.

And there is nothing to do with the new android permission model introduced as of Android 6. It is rather a linux filesystem related permission.